# Twilio - Using conference announce to update caller

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

My question: Can Twilio Announcements be used when there is only a single participant in the conference?

My Test Application: Is a simple node app that keeps a caller waiting while work is done in the background, with periodic updates on progress to the caller, before finally moving the call to a real person.

The problem: I saw Announcements and that this would excellent for my needs.

My node test app successfully dumps each incoming call into its own unique conference. I later attempt to announce an update on the background processing while the caller is waiting.

```
    client.conferences(conferenceSid)
  .update({announceUrl:'https://cccbae85.ngrok.io/twilio/announce'})
    .then(result => console.log('success'))
    .catch(error => console.log('conference error = ' + error));
```

The following results:
conference error = Error: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACX*/Conferences/CFb15222ac23964077e8161c819cd9dcca.json was not found

When I change this to use a conference AND participant:

```
    client.conferences(conferenceSid)
    .participants (particpantCallSid)
  .update({announceUrl:'https://cccbae85.ngrok.io/twilio/announce'})
    .then(result => console.log('success'))
    .catch(error => console.log('conference error = ' + error));
```

The result is 'success', meaning the conferenceSid was accepted, but I never see any call to the announceUrl (no errors in Twilio, no attempts through ngok).

So back to my question, can Announcements be used in conferences that have a single participant, or do I need to go back to having a "bot" jump into the conference, say something, and jump back out.

OR - did I royally mess up my understanding of Announce....

Thanks!!

Comment: That's an interesting issue. I'm an evangelist at Twilio but I've not worked with Conference Announcements yet. I've asked the team to see what they have to say.

Comment: @philnash Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: From following issue, I think it is still not possible for a single participant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755810/twilio-api-conference-call-announce-url-returns-20404-but-status-update-works