# Twilio API - Conference call announce_url returns 20404, but status update works

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm attempting to announce a "please wait" message periodically in an ongoing conference call using the Twilio API. I found some guidance via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17846262/85359, however when I attempt to `client.conferences('CXXXXXXXID').update(announce_url: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.please_wait_message_url)` I receive:

```
Twilio::REST::RestError: [HTTP 404] 20404 : Unable to update record
The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/asdf/Conferences/CXXXXXXXID.json was not found
```

However, I've verified that the conference lookup does work (not a real 404) by also trying `.update(status: 'completed')` and I'm seeing that API call work and the conference call end.

I'm guessing this has something to do with my URL used and the error message is very non-descriptive. I have confirmed that a `POST` to the URL I'm passing in does return some TwiML via Postman API testing tool.

I'm using the latest version of the `twilio-ruby` gem (`5.20.1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After receiving email support from Twilio, it turns out that the conference `announce_url` feature only works when there are multiple participants present on the conference call.

They recommend providing your own `waitUrl` music with your message overlaid if you're wanting a periodic "please wait" messages as well as music.